# How do I connect two PS3 to the same PSN account

Tags: ps3, psn

I have two ps3's and wanted to know if I can connect them to the same PSN account as when I try to log the second one onto the account I created on the first one it says you cannot log onto someone eses account (or something like that).  I set up a psn account on the second ps3 but want to use the same one as the first.

The first machine was switched off at the time; I want to be able to download purchases onto both my machines.

Comment: Have you tried the simple act of logging out of one before playing on the other? (Or are you trying to use the same account on two PS3s' at the same time?)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by logging on to two PS3's at the same time?

Comment: I hope I am doing this right bit of a noob.  I want to be able to access what I buy on both machines.

Answer (score 2):

You can't log on to the same PSN account on two PS3 machines at the same time.

You can have the account present on both PS3 machines, but as you've observed, once you (try to) log on the second PS3 you get the error message, and you'll have to log off the first PS3 before you can log on to the same (with the same account).

As such, you will not be able to be logged in on two different PS3 machines with the same account.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be able to play the games you downloaded on each console at the same time if you feel like it. Me and my son share a psn account, and I can download what he buys, and he can download what I buy. The misconception that you have to be logged in to play downloaded games is false. You can play games that are downloaded without even logging in. Both PS3's will have the same download list because they share one psn account but have different user names.....I hope this helps you out. Good luck and GOD bless...